# How do I see which files need to be saved in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm using VS Code and have a lot of files open. I frequently see the photo I attached on the left side tool bar in "Explorer" button showing me how many files are unsaved. How do I quickly find those files?

Comment: just enable autosave

Comment: @drum edited. maybe I don't wanted to save. Just want to be able to cycle through all of the files that I edited quickly.

Comment: show the `OPEN EDITORS` view, not saved files are marked with a dot

Answer (score 0):

You can just look in the tab handles of your open editors. Or if you want to see a list, use the "Open Editors" view under the Explorer View. You can focus it using the `Explorer: Focus on Open Editors View`, which is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>. Editors with unsaved changes will be decorated with a dot, similar to how [a dot is displayed in the tab handles for editors with unsaved changes](/q/76024956/11107541).